# Modify Voice over accessibility traverse order in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

In an iOS app written with Objective C, when **Voice Over** is on, The cancel button on the top-left and the save button on the top-right, those two buttons are in the same top bar on the view, now the order is **cancel->save->other views** on the page. But I need to actually traverse and edit all other elements before I can save, so I need to set the traverse order as **cancel ->all other view->save button**.

I saw some solutions that create new views to group elements or reorder accessibilityElementOrders. But I am just changing one button, is there an easy way like **android:accessibilityTraversalAfter** in Objective C?

Comment: You need to include some extra details ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to better express the problem you are dealing with: how the buttons are positioned in relation to each other? From what direction you try to switch the focus from? What happens and what the expected behaviour is?

Comment: The cancel button on the top-left and the save button on the top-right, those two buttons are in the same top bar on the view, now the order is cancel->save->other views on the page. But I need to actually traverse and edit all other elements before I can save, so I need to set the traverse order as cancel ->all other view->save button.

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely a good idea to modify the order of elements on the screen, especially in iOS. VoiceOver is used by people of many different abilities, including partially-sighted people, who would be confused about why the order doesn’t match the display. And even those who are completely blind will expect to interact with your app in the way other apps work. It’s a very common pattern to have buttons at the top when you can skip the action, but at the bottom if you have to do something with the content first. As much as possible, you should follow those conventions so users won’t be surprised at how your app behaves (a bigger issue for users of AX tools, since recovering can be much more challenging).

The way VO works is by creating a parallel object hierarchy and traversing that using a few simple rules like geometric order. So no, if you insist on modifying the order of the buttons, you will have to modify that hierarchy which means something like modifying `accessibilityElements`.